# C++ dynamic array, increasing capacity

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, capacity

I'm trying to implement a dynamic array and here is my function for increasing the capacity

```
int* changeCapacity(int *arr, int length, int newCapacity) {
    int *newArr = new int[newCapacity];

    if(length > newCapacity){
        return 0;
    } else {
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            newArr[i] = arr[i];
        }
        delete[] arr;
        arr = newArr;
        return arr;
    }
}
```

This is the error i get:

> speicher(2465,0x7fff7cfc2310) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f9742403910: pointer being freed was not allocated
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

i'm calling it like this:

```
int* addElement(int *arr, int& length, int& capacity, int val){
if(length >= capacity){
    capacity = capacity * 2;
    changeCapacity(arr, length, capacity);

    arr[length] = val;
    length += 1;
    return arr;
}else{

    arr[length] = val;
    length += 1;
    return arr;
}
```

}

Comment: If `length > newCapacity`, you are leaking memory.

Comment: You're using C++. Use `std::vector<int>` which will take care of all this. Then you get to go home early.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Why are you assuming he CAN use the standard library? Most probably he's a student trying to implement a vector by himself.

Comment: Can you tell us how you call the function?

Comment: Why do you assume (s)he's a he?

Comment: `arr[length]` is out of bounds on an array of `length` objects, but I don't think that's the issue. Neither of these functions is calling `free()`, so I think the problem may be elsewhere... Also, in `changeCapacity()`, I think returning 0 for the case where the new requested capacity is less than the existing capacity is probably not a wise design choice...

Comment: @twalberg agreed the return 0 is a bad choice. It prevents you from using `arr = changeCapacity(arr, length, capacity);` and makes the return value less useful.

Comment: Don't ignore the return of `changeCapacity`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a better way of doing it. Everything is well explained in the comments for anyone who wants to learn:

```
        #include <iostream>
        using namespace std;

        int* changeCapacity(int *arr, int length, int newCapacity);
        int* addElement(int *arr, int& length, int& capacity, int val);

        int main(){
            int length = 0; // no inital elements in array
            int capacity = 1; // initial capacity is one
            int* arr = new int[capacity]; // allocating space for values
            int* temp; // pointer for storing temporary values
            /* loop for adding elements to the array */
            for(int i=0;i<21;i++){
                temp = addElement(arr,length,capacity,i); // adding an element to the array
                if(temp == NULL) { // checks if execution was successful
                    cout<< "NULL returned...\n Exiting Now...";
                    return 0; // exits the program on failure
                }
                arr = temp; // changing the value of arr
            }
            /* loop for printing the array */
            for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
                cout<<arr[i]<<" ";          
            }
            return 0;
        }
        /* function for increasing the capacity of array */
        int* changeCapacity(int *arr, int length, int newCapacity) {
            int *newArr = new int[newCapacity]; // definging a new array

            if(length > newCapacity){ // checking if the length of the array is valid
                cout<< "invalid length of array\n";
                return NULL;
            } else {
                /* loop for transferring values to the new array */
                for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
                    newArr[i] = arr[i];
                }
                delete[] arr; // deleting the old array (clears the memory of the old array)
                // arr = newArr; removed as this is not needed
                return newArr; // returns the new array
            }
        }

        /* function for adding a new element to the array */
        int* addElement(int *arr, int& length, int& capacity, int val){
        if(length >= capacity){ // checks if the array has space for storing the given value or not
            capacity = capacity * 2; // doubles the capacity of the array
            int* temp = changeCapacity(arr, length, capacity); // changes the size of the array to the new one
            if(temp == NULL){ // checking if a null was returned
                cout<< "Failed to change capacity\n";
                return NULL; // returning  NULL
            }
            arr = temp; // the value of arr was not changed in your code (problem corrected)
            arr[length] = val; // stores the value in the array
            length += 1; // increasing the number of element count of the array
            return arr; // returns the new array
        }else{
            arr[length] = val; // stores the value in the array
            length += 1; // increasing the number of element count of the array
            return arr; // returns the new array
        }
        }
```

Comment: There is a memory leak in this code too. The same mistake in the question.

Comment: i think its better to preallocate space for elements before hand instead of allocating space for them everytime you insert a new element. That would require you to traverse the whole array for each insertion. I could have used a linked list or a vector for this problem but given the question i thought it was better to preserve the original code of the question. Moreover its also keeping track of the memory allocated.

Answer (score 1):

*I assume that your problem must come from two things IMO* :

**First**:

```
changeCapacity(arr, length, capacity);
arr[length] = val;
```

Here you doesn't get the new **arr** value (returned by **changeCapacity()**).
So your function **addElement()** will return Wrong pointer and on your next **addElement()** that will do free memory corruption.

Why do you have to get the new arr value?

You do the same as here

```
a = 1;
changeVar(a);
// value of a here?

int changeVar(int a)
{
   a = 5;
   return (a);
}
```

How will be the value of **a**? 1 because the argument of changeVar is a local variable.

**Second:**

You give a **NULL** value on your **addElement()** function.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are changing the address of `arr`, in which you have to pass the pointer by reference. Do this:

```
int* changeCapacity(int *&arr, int length, int newCapacity)
```

Comment: If the OP uses the return value this will not be needed since the new pointer is returned from changeCapacity.

Comment: and this is why complete code examples are important. It could be that the real issue is how he's using the function, not the function itself.

Comment: The OP would also have to fix the return 0 when the capacity did not need to increase. That is a bad choice.

Comment: Or use their own return value

Comment: Why return int* if you give a reference in parameter?

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat a guess based on the error message, but you have shown:

```
int* addElement(int *arr, int& length, int& capacity, int val)
{ //...
  changeCapacity(arr, length, capacity);
  //...
}
```

which calls:

```
int* changeCapacity(int *arr, int length, int newCapacity)
{ //...
  delete[] arr;
  //...
}
```

However, the original source of the `arr` argument to `addElement()` is unknown given the code you have posted so far. Are you by chance doing something like this:

```
foo()
{ int array[N];
  //...
  addElement(array, ...);
  //...
}
```

or maybe calling `addElement()` with a global array variable? In either of those cases, the original array is not allocated via a `new[]` to match the `delete[]`, and this would appear to be what the runtime library is complaining about. The value of the pointer stated in the error message tends to make me think it was allocated on the stack initially.

Of course the other issues, like not capturing the return value of `changeCapacity()` and/or `addElement()`, and the possibility that `changeCapacity()` might return a NULL pointer are still valid as well, and should be fixed.